# Login with facebook and chat with Scringo

Tags: ios, facebook, scringo

Hi I am having trouble to login my ios app with facebook. I have Scringo package, so I want to use facebook to login first then using scringo to chat. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Disclosure: I work for Scringo ;-)

Sure you can, it's quite simple, and Scringo is made just for this.
You should set the Facebook app ID in your plist.

You can find a more elaborate explanation here:
http://docs.scringo.com/ios-guides/guides/connect-to-social-networks/